# How Do I Clean-up noisy pixels in transparent .png using gimp 2.28?

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have converted a .gif to transparent gif using gimnp 2.  I export as .png.  When I Insert Picture into a MS Publisher .pub trifold.  I send it Backward and I see the text over the pic.

All is okay except the png has a few 'floating' dark pixels near the object in the pic (a church).  How do I get rid of those individuals 'noise' pixels?

Comment: You can't just erase them in GIMP?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

- `Layer>Transparency>Alpha to selection` to select the non-transparent pixels
- `Select>Sharpen`
- `Select>Shrink` by one or 2 pixels: selection will disappear on the random pixels
- `Select>Grow` by one more pixel than in the step above: you get back the original selection (slightly bigger) but without the stray pixels
- `Select>Invert` and `Edit>Clear`

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks